# SQL Server Multiple Rows into One row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with lot of records. I provided a sample of 1 record (4 rows)

[image]

Need the rows to be combined as follows

[image]

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select col1, max(col2), max(col3), max(col4)
from t
group by col1;
```

Note that the data you describe sounds like it comes from an aggregation query.  Usually this is more easily fixed by fixing that query and fixing the `group by` keys.